# Automating a custom QGraphicsObject control in an external QT based process

Tags: automation, injection, qt

I have injected a DLL into an external application that is based on the QT framework. I, then, use the method `QApplication::allWidgets()` and iterate through the list of widgets to find a `QGraphicsView` that represents the window I want to interact with.

The buttons and other controls in the scene are all derived from `QGraphicsObject`. But, I don't have the source. So, I can only cast to `QGraphicsObject` and not to the actual type.

The list of methods from the meta-object is incomplete, which is to be expected, because I cast to a `QGraphicsObject`. I can find the method names using IDA though.

Is it possible to call a particular method, and how would you do it?

Comment: I would probably try and walk the objects vtable (don't cast it to QGraphicsObject).

Comment: As an aside, are you sure the functions you're calling are thread-safe?

Comment: @fileoffset I will try this, but I am not familiar with how to find the method in the vtable. I will do some research, but if you have a link to a relevant article, please post it.

Comment: @JasonGeffner I am not sure if it is. Is there anyway to determine this without having the source?

Comment: Unfortunately there is no standard for vtables, each compiler can implement it how it likes. Can you determine which compiler&version was used to create the binary? If it was MSVS, what you can do is install that version of MSVS, and then write a small test program with a basic class that inherits from QGraphicsObject. Then you can compile it with some special flags (see answer #2 here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/302446/how-can-one-inspect-a-vtable-in-visual-c) and MSVS will output the format of the object, including the vtable.

Comment: @user2173399: The official documentation for the functions (or the controls or the framework in general) should specify whether or not they're thread-safe.